# cambiar de consulta mysql a un simple ciclo for

Tags: php

Poseo los siguientes variables;

```
$minimo = 2500;
$maximo = 300000000;
$multiplo = 2500;
```

Estas variables las utilizo para hacer una seleccion en una base de datos y asi como esta funciona perfectamente:

```
// primera opcion
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `monto_recarga` WHERE mod (monto, '$multiplo') = 0 AND monto >= $monto_minimo AND monto <= $monto_maximo ORDER BY monto ASC";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

    echo '<option value="'.$valores['monto'].'">'.number_format($valores['monto'],2,',','.').' Bs.</option>';
  }
```

Pero requiero que esto se ejecute sin necesidad de consultar la base de datos motivado a que los montos son muy cambiantes y me gustaria solo modificar los valores y que el sistema calcule el resto de los datos, mi codigo del ciclo for cuelga el server y no funciona

```
//segunda opción no funciona

for($i=$monto_minimo;$i<$monto_maximo+1;$i++){
  if($i%$multiplo==0){
echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.number_format($i,2,',','.').' Bs.</option>';
  }  }
```

Los valores que debe darme como resultado son valores como por ejemplo:

```
minimo 200
maximo 1000
multiplo 200

200
400
600
800
1000
```

Comment: Buenas, José, no tengo un servidor PHP a mano, pero he probado tu bucle y salen un total de 130000 opciones para el select. En StackOverflow indicaban hace un tiempo que algunos navegadores limitan el máximo de estas opciones a 10000 (10K) https://stackoverflow.com/a/22330536/2553194 Aparte de esta limitación, no parece muy usable un select con tantisimos valores. ¿Seguro que eso es lo que quieres hacer? De todas formas, el servidor no debería colgarse a la hora de generar la página.

Comment: Saludos, de hecho es lo que hace con lo que denomine primera opcion pero cuando cambian los valores de `$minimo = 2500;
$maximo = 300000000;
$multiplo = 2500;` tambien debo estar modificando los valores de mi tabla `monto_recarga` y es lo que no quisiera continuar haciendo